# How to perform cross validation without using paramgrid Builder in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to do a sklearn kind of cross validation in pyspark without using **ParamGrid Builder**.

```
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression(regParam=0.1,elasticNet=0.2,maxIter=100)
crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=lr,
                          evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
                          numFolds=2)
```

Is it possible to perform the cross validation in this way without using paramGrid Builder? My usecase is I want to pass the parameters into the linear regression class as arguments but not as paramGrid object.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would be to only provide the parameters you want to use in your ParamGrid:

```
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
  .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1]) \
  .addGrid(lr.elasticNet, [0.2]) \
  .addGrid(lr.maxIter, [100]) 
  .build()

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=lr,
                estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid, 
                evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
                numFolds=2)
```

You can always code your own version of K-fold, splitting your dataset in K parts with :

```
fold1, fold2 = df.randomSplit([0.5,0.5])
folds = [fold1, fold2]
res = []
for fold in folds:
    train, test = fold.randomSplit([0.80,0.20])
    model.train(train)
    res.append(model.evaluate(test))

do_what_you_want(res)
```